# How Build sql database in Xamarin without using a listView and PrimaryKey

Tags: android, database, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin.forms

previously I have created a data model as below and I have successfully connect data into a `listView` to xamlpages for the `public class student`.

Then, how do you connect database sql from a `public class school` that is only input once without using a `listView` and `PrimaryKey`?

```
using SQLite;
using System;

namespace SchoolData.Models
{
    public class Student
    {   
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int IdSis { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string PicStudent { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class School
    {
        public string SchoolName { get; set; } //without primary key or single entry
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Vision { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XamlPage code overview:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="School Name:"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding SchoolName}"/>
    <Label Text="Address:"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Address}"/>
    <Label Text="Vision:"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Vision}"/>
    
    <Button Text="Save" Clicked="SaveClick"/> //save all entry
    <Button Text="Clear" Clicked="ClearClick"/> //clear all entry
</StackLayout>
```

Then how do the C # write command create, and update `public class school` connection to XamlPage above.

Thank's.

Comment: there are numerous existing tutorials and samples on how to use sqlite with Xamarin.  Have you read any of them?  ie, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Comment: It's been almost a week I looked for references that discuss this but could not find. most of the material using primarykey and contained in listview view.

Comment: and for articles from learn.microsoft.com about xamarin more directed at the xaml layout ... I'm stuck here

Comment: inserting a row in a table is the same regardless of whether or not the table has a PK.  And I have no idea why you think ListView has any relevance.

Comment: i confused in `public Task<List<Student>> GetAdmKelasAsync()
{
    return _database.Table<Student>().ToListAsync();
}
public Task<Student> GetSiswaAsync(int id)
{
    return _database.Table<Student>()
    .Where(i => i.IdSis == id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}` to call it

Comment: whereas in the example I wrote above, I want to retrieve data from the `public class school` and display it without a `listview`

Comment: then you need to build.a page that contains the UI elements for a single Student (possibly a Label for DateTime and an Image control) and populate them with data from your query.

Comment: in this problem there are many students with one school name. therefore I want to take only name of school, which for school data can only be filled in and updated, but not added to a row of other school names. then displayed on page.

Comment: that is a db design problem.  Use a unique constraint on the name, or just check for existing rows before inserting.

Comment: Is stack in SchoolData.Models still wrong or needs updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then how do the C # write command create, and update public class school connection to XamlPage above.
>
> in this problem there are many students with one school name. therefore I want to take only name of school, which for school data can only be filled in and updated,

If you want to insert school in sqlite table, you can take a look the following code:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label Text="School Name:" />
        <Entry x:Name="txtschool" />
        <Label Text="Address:" />
        <Entry x:Name="txtaddress" />
        <Label Text="Vision:" />
        <Entry x:Name="txtvision" />

        <Button Clicked="SaveClick" Text="Save" />

        <Button Clicked="ClearClick" Text="Clear" />

    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public SQLiteConnection conn;
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conn = GetSQLiteConnection();
        conn.CreateTable<School>();

    }
    public SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection()
    {
        var fileName = "studentdatabase.db";
        var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);

        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);

        return connection;
    }

    private void SaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        School school = new School();
        school.SchoolName = txtschool.Text.ToString();
        school.Address = txtaddress.Text.ToString();
        school.Vision = txtvision.Text.ToString();
        var data = conn.Table<School>();
      
        var d1 = data.Where(x => x.SchoolName == school.SchoolName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (d1 == null)
        {
            conn.Insert(school);
            Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully Added");
        }
        else
        {
            school.Id = d1.Id;
            conn.Update(school);
            Console.WriteLine("Already school name Exist, update");
        }
        txtaddress.Text = "";
        txtschool.Text = "";
        txtvision.Text = "";
       
      
    }

    private void ClearClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtaddress.Text = "";
        txtschool.Text = "";
        txtvision.Text = "";
    }
}
```

For you school model, please add primary key, because the sqlite table need one primary key.

```
public class School
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; } 
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Vision { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: for sql conection I'm `using SQLite`, and for Path `using System.IO`. But, result debug error `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`. maybe there is some code writing wrong?

Comment: @anoaanoa Where you have this error message? Can you provide your code here?

Comment: @YanLimaBenua Do you created  School table before? I don't see where you create your table.

Comment: on top my question: using SQLite;
using System;

`namespace SchoolData.Models
{
    public class Student
    {   
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int IdSis { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string PicStudent { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class School
    {
        public string SchoolName { get; set; } //without primary key or single entry
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Vision { get; set; }
    }
}`

Comment: @YanLimaBenua I mean that you have use `conn.CreateTable<School>();` to create School Table in sqlite database?If you still have problem, please provide your sample on github, I will download your sample to test at my side.

Comment: @YanLimaBenua You are Anoaanoa, if yes, please reply using anoaanoa roles.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT no, it looks like I have a similar problem ..

Answer (score 0):

@Cherry_Bu
on mainpage.xaml.cs

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EditSekolah
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SQLiteConnection conn;
        private string path;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        }
        

        private void SaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            School school = new School();
            school.SchoolName = txtschool.Text.ToString();
            school.Address = txtaddress.Text.ToString();
            school.Vision = txtvision.Text.ToString();
            var data = conn.Table<School>();

            var d1 = data.Where(x => x.SchoolName == school.SchoolName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (d1 == null)
            {
                conn.Insert(school);
                Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully Added");
            }
            else
            {
                school.Id = d1.Id;
                conn.Update(school);
                Console.WriteLine("Already school name Exist, update");
            }
            txtaddress.Text = "";
            txtschool.Text = "";
            txtvision.Text = "";


        }

        private void ClearClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtaddress.Text = "";
            txtschool.Text = "";
            txtvision.Text = "";
        }
    }
    public class School
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Vision { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and on mainpage.xaml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EditSekolah.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="School Name:" />
            <Entry x:Name="txtschool" />
            <Label Text="Address:" />
            <Entry x:Name="txtaddress" />
            <Label Text="Vision:" />
            <Entry x:Name="txtvision" />

            <Button Clicked="SaveClick" Text="Save" />

            <Button Clicked="ClearClick" Text="Clear" />

        </StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Start developing now" FontSize="Title" Padding="30,10,30,10"/>
        <Label Text="Make changes to your XAML file and save to see your UI update in the running app with XAML Hot Reload. Give it a try!" FontSize="16" Padding="30,0,30,0"/>
        <Label FontSize="16" Padding="30,24,30,0">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                        <Span Text="Learn more at "/>
                        <Span Text="https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

every time you debug, it always ends up getting an error. I don't know why this problem can happen ..